# How can I insert a value on every index of array using a loop and slice and/or concat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, concatenation

I'm currently doing an assignment for school and could really use your help. 
I have to declare a function which takes two arguments, x and an array, arr. It has to return an array which contains multiple arrays with x inserted into respectively index 0 in the first array, index 1 in the second array and so on until there's no more numbers in the array. See picture of an example and for clarification of what the final result is expected to look like. It has to work on any given array and the assignment specifies that slice() and concat() would be good to use. [example of assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rawC3.png)

```
function insert_all_positions (x, arr) {  
    var newArr = [];  
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {  
      return(arr.concat(x)); }
   };
```

This just adds the x-value to the end of the array and I have to loop it so the value will be inserted at all indexes. I'm thinking the array.splice() method can be used, I'm just not sure how as I'm not particularly experienced with it. Thank you :)

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Comment: I agree with Nina, that OP should provide some "own effort" into the question, but to close this question on the grounds of "Needs more focus" seems a bit harsh to me as the question itself appers to be clearly formulated. And of course, we are not here as general "homework suppliers" - but on the other hand, we aren't teachers either ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nina already said: the idea of assignments is, that you try something yourself which we can then help you to improve.

Nonetheless, here is one simple way of doing what was required:

```js
function iap(v,arr){
 var l=arr.length, ret=[];
 for (var i=0;i<=l;i++) ret.push(arr.slice(0,i).concat([v],arr.slice(i,l)));
 return ret;
}

console.log(iap(8,[1,2,3]));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the first time I'm asking a question on stackoverflow, so I wasn't really sure as to what was expected! Next time I will definitely provide more insight to my own code and what I have tried beforehand :) Thank you again!

Comment: You are most welcome and, of course: welcome to Stack Overflow! As you just experienced yourself: posting a good question is not easy! Don't feel discouraged. Remember to carry out your own research before posting anything here and - most of all - show us what you have tried. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function myFunc(x,arr){
   let result =[]
   for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    let arrToAdd = [...arr]
    arrToAdd[i]=x
    result.push(arrToAdd)
   }
   return result
}
```

You create a result array that you push your arrays into, then you run a loop that will run the exact number of times as the length of your argument arr. Each iteration of the loop creates a new array that is a copy of arr and then you just change one number in it each time and add the entire array to the result.